# Create package with dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x

Do you know how to create package from my python application to be installable on Windows without internet connection? I want, for example, to create tar.gz file with my python script and all dependencies. Then install such package on windows machine with python3.7 already installed. I tried setuptools but i don't see possibility to include dependencies. Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

Their are several Java tutorials on how to make installers that are offline. You have your python project and just use a preprogrammed Java installer to then put all of the 'goodies' inside of. Then you have an installer for windows. And its an executable.